# Apache Commons FileUpload: problems uploading files greater than 100kb using HTTPS

Tags: tomcat, servlets, https, apache-commons-fileupload

I'have a java web app that uses Apache Commons FileUpload for uploading files using servlet.

My base code worked perfectly for years on a plain http environment (Apache Tomcat 8.5).

I've changed my environment to work with HTTPS, using a Let's Encrypt certificate using connector configured with org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol.

My uploads now suddenly fail if files are greater than 100kb. Same files uploaded successfully using plain HTTP environment.

This is the exception logged:

```
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. java.io.IOException: The socket [925,024,592] associated with this connection has been closed.
```

this is the code fragment i use for manage request:

```
  DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();          
  File repository = (File) 


  request.getServletContext().getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");

  factory.setRepository(repository);

  ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
  upload.setHeaderEncoding(encoding); 

  multipartItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
```

Tomcat settings:

```
 <Connector 
    port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    redirectPort="443"      
  />

<Connector 
    port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
    maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true"  
>
    <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate 
            certificateKeyFile="D:/prj/certificati/private.key"
            certificateFile="D:/prj/certificati/certificate.crt"
            certificateChainFile="D:/prj/certificati/ca_bundle.crt"
            type="RSA" 
        />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

I've researched about this issue, few cases, no solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The time upload when using http2 is too short

try to change the upgrade protocol with

```
<UpgradeProtocol overheadWindowUpdateThreshold="-1" overheadDataThreshold="-1" writeTimeout="-1" streamWriteTimeout="-1" streamReadTimeout="-1" maxHeaderSize="8192" maxConcurrentStreams="300" readTimeout="-1" className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" compressibleMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript,application/json" compression="on" compressionMinSize="1024"/>
```

Comment: This helped me fix a customer issue in Production, so thank you! I didn't realise you could put config inside <UpgradeProtocol>, and putting it in the enclosing <Connector> didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like the client has tripped the overhead threshold protection.

As a short term fix you probably want to see a lower value for:
overheadDataThreshold

see: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http2.html

possibly as low as zero.

Longer term you should ideally look into why the client is sending
small, non-final DATA frames since that as inefficient and has been
identified as a potential DoS vector in some servers (not Tomcat but we
block it as abusive behaviour anyway).

Depending on what the client is doing, you may need to adjust the other
over head thresholds as well. If you have a reproducible test case,
enabling debug for http2 in logging.properties should shed some light on
exactly what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mark. At the moment I've resolved my issue dropping the upgrade to http2 protocol, my web application now is in production, it works perfectly and I don't need other fixes. if it's not broken, don't fix it :-) .

Anytime, I'm aware now of which issue causes the problem, so if I'll encounter it again in another context I'll investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. Apparently, this issue is caused by this directive:

```
 <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
```

removing that, it works.

Comment: That's not really a solution, this directive enables HTTP/2, so by removing it, you've downgraded the protocol. Which will decrease performance if you're serving large amount of files during page load.

Answer (score 0):

See https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59564

Upgrading tomcat fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).